# What is the conditional expected value?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, random-variables

Consider two random variables, X and Y, with joint density function,
\begin{align} f_{X,Y}(x,y)=8xy, \qquad(0<x<1,0<y<x) \end{align}
Calculate $\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y)$.

I've tried this,
$$f_{X\mid Y=y}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}=\frac{8xy}{\int_0^18xy\;dx}=\frac{8xy}{8y\left[\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_0^1}=\frac{8xy}{4y}=2x$$
$$\mathbb{E}(X\mid Y=y) = \int_0^1 xf_{X\mid Y=y} \; dx = \int_0^1 2x^2 \; dx = 2\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_0^1 =2\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$
but my book says it is:
$$\frac{2(1-y^3)}{3(1-y^2)},\;(0<y<1)$$
What I'm doing wrong? Help please!

Comment: $f_{X,Y}$ only has support on $x>y$ and you aren't taking this into account.

Comment: So what I'm doing wrong, I don't understand.

Comment: You should integrate $f_{X,Y}$ over $x\in(y,1)$ to find $f_Y$.

Comment: For instance you need $f_Y(y)= \int_y^1 8xy dx.$ the lower limit of $y$ is needed since $f_{X,Y}$ is zero for $x<y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f_Y(y) = \underbrace{\int\limits_{\{\, x \,:\, 0\,<\,y\,<\,x\,<\,1 \,\}}}_\text{see below} f_{X,Y} (x,y) \, dx = \int_y^1 8xy \, dx = \cdots
$$
The thing over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ was given at the outset and tells you  over what range of values you need to integrate.